# How can I plot both lines and dots for different data in the same chart

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm working with Flot charts and I want to plot a chart with a line data series and a dot data series. One array making a line, and a one array making dots.

However, I'm not able to achieve this?

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [
                    { data: prices, label: "Prices" },
                    { data: average, label: "Average", yaxis: 2 },
                    { data: error, label: "Error", yaxis: 3 }
                ], {
                    points: [{},{},{ show: true, radius: 10, lineWidth: 4, fill: false }],
                    xaxes: [ { mode: "time" } ],
                    yaxes: [ 
                        {  }, 
                        {
                            alignTicksWithAxis: 1,
                            position: "right",
                            min: -110,
                            max: 10
                        },
                        {
                            alignTicksWithAxis: 1,
                            position: "right",
                            visible: false,
                            ticks: []
                        }
                    ],
                    legend: { position: "sw" }
                });
```

Here prices and average are two data line arrays, and the errors are supposed to be visualizing dots in the chart. But I only have lines. I cant "mix and match"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `points` and `lines` options to your data series objects, [like so](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format):

```
var data = [{
    data: [[0, 150], [1, 200], [2, 250], [3, 120], [4, 90]],
    points: { show: false },
    lines: { show: true }
},
{
    data: [[0, 200], [1, 100], [2, 150], [3, 70], [4, 30]],
    points: { show: true },
    lines: { show: false }
}];
```

[This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vf10ha5v/) has an example of a series plotting lines, while another series plots points.